Highest reslution video and fps in 2025?
Whats the cost of say 25 k video device to record in 2025 and what is highest fps renting price of such an equipment? So that we can see it in laptop screens in say 2030. Or is 4k resolution the limit of eye?
I want to consumme 2Tb cloud storage fast.
